# Enforce a method call on class exit

Tags: c#, dispose

I have a base class that when any class inherited from will add a GUID to a list in another singleton class. I want to have a method in the base class that will remove the GUID from the list when the inherited class has completed its execution. I was looking at putting a method call in a Dispose method but wasn't sure if this was the right way to go as I want the method call to remove the GUID to happen as soon as possible so I did not want to wait for the .NET GC to begin it's work. Also as I have never implemented Dispose before can I just add the IDisposable interface to my base class and create a Dispose method that includes the GUID removal logic or do you have to explicitly include other logic in a Dispose method?

Comment: Can you clarify please: you use the term 'class exit', 'when the class has completed its execution'.    Since you're writing the class, you write the code which does the execution, so you can simply remove the GUID from the list at that point?

Comment: If you implement IDisposable and put the code ot remove the Guid in your Dispose method then it will be called when your class is disposed of. You can force this to happen automatically by using the using syntax or try...finally dispose.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing things, actually.

The garbage collector will never call `Dispose` on your class. You should implement `IDisposable` so that a client can ensure that the cleanup method is always called:

```
using System;

class BaseClass : IDisposable {
    bool _guidremoved = false;
    public void RemoveGuid() {
        if (!_guidremoved) {
            _guidremoved = true;
            // your logic here                
        }
    }
    public void Dispose() {
        RemoveGuid();
    }
}

class Derived : BaseClass { 
}

static class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        using (Derived d = new Derived()) { 
            // do stuff here...

            // call RemoveGuid explicitly, if needed
            d.RemoveGuid();
        } // when we exit this block, Dispose is called
    }
}
```

In this example, the `using` block ensures that the `RemoveGuid` method is called by `Dispose()` if the line with `d.RemoveGuid()` is not reached.

The garbage collector would, instead, call the destructor (or better, the `Finalize` method) on your class when it runs, but that would probably not be the proper place to remove the GUID in your case.

Check [Implementing Finalize and Dispose to Clean Up Unmanaged Resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) for more details.

Comment: `IDisposable` is not just for cleanup “in case something goes wrong”. It's also for cleanup when the work is successfully done, and the resource is not needed anymore. It's called when leaving the `using` whether an exception was thrown or not. So, in this case, there is no need to call `d.RemoveGuid()` manually.

Answer (score 0):

There is no magic in writing the Dispose method. It is no different from any other method. If you do not call it the system will not do it for you.

EXCEPT:

If you really want to make sure that those precious resources are cleaned up properly, you also need to build some safeguards for the situations when the GC gets to your object even though the Dispose method was not called in a usual way.

The way to do it is to also call it from the object destructor and as you do it there are a few things to watch out. First of all when the Dispose runs from the destructor it happens on a thread different from the main thread of your app. Also you cannot use any of the objects your object references by this time they might'of been collected.

Comment: In general, if you *really, really* need to clean up resources, consider what happens in the case of a sudden power failure. That's generally the worst-case scenario, and if you can recover from that you get most other recoveries for free.

Comment: @MSalters: I do not think that memory or handle leak is of a big concern in cases of power failure :)

Comment: Of course not :). But memory doesn't even need `Dispose`. I was considering very big temporary files; I've personally seen an application leak 2 GB temp files.